# Change the size of a graphic inside a legend

Tags: graphics

I have this graph:

```
ShowLegend[
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}], 
{{{Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 5], Sin[x] > 0}, {Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], Sin[x] < 0}}}]
```

[image]

and I would like to change the size of the disks in the legend. Unfortunately, using the ImageSize option doesn't work `Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]},ImageSize -> 2]`

What should I do in this case?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Öskå version 9, although I might migrate to version 10 very soon, especially if you tell me it's easier to do so in version 10

Comment: What I was about to tell you is that ``Needs["PlotLegends`"]`` is obsolete, the `Plot` option `PlotLegends` should be used now.

Comment: @Öskå Mathematica 9 told me it was obsolete, but it still seems to work, and I've seen many people on Stackexchange who don't recommend using PlotLegends? Was it before and now it works well?

Comment: You may have seen many people who don't recommend using `PlotLegend` but `PlotLegends` instead :) Since _v9_ `PlotLegend` has been replaced by `PlotLegends` and it works pretty fine I think :)

Comment: Anyway, you can use `Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled@.2]` (or any number you want) instead of a radius of `1`. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ECMg5.png).

Comment: @Öskå in fact my problem is that I use Show to plot multiple graphics. Following this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/using-plotlegends-with-show-messes-up-the-graphics , it seems like the best solution is to use ShowLegend in this situation and PlotLegends won't work with Show?

Comment: Have you tried [that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51883/1356)?

Comment: @Öskå it works really well!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value of `LegendMarkerSize` to the size that you want. Look more into `PlotLegends` and `SwatchLegend` in the documentation.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[{Blue, Red}, {"Sin(x) > 0", "Sin(x) < 0"}, 
   LegendMarkers -> Graphics[Disk[]], LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
   LegendFunction -> Framed]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]