# How to add a plot legend to a Show expression

Tags: plotting

This is the code I'm using:

```
 Show[{graph1, graph2},
 PlotRange -> Automatic,
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Lambda](nm)", "k and n"},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Wavelength (nm)", "k,n values"},
 BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, FontColor -> Blue]
```

[image]

My problem is that I can't figure out how to add a plot legend.

Comment: You can only use options for `Graphics` with `Show`, not options for the original functions that created the plots. If you want to use `PlotLabel` then you should do it in the command you use to create `graph1` or `graph2`.

Comment: Duplicate? [(3518)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3518/121), [(51880)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51880/121).  If you no longer have the original data, but do have the plot Graphics, see [(19859)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19859/121) and [(59805)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59805/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example, writing:

```
p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Blue}, {"y1"}], PlotStyle -> Blue];

p2 = Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red}, {"y2"}], PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[{p1, p2}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

I get:

[image]

which is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are plotting lists of data points, why not plot the two data sets on one list plot?

```
{data1, data2} = Table[{t, #[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, .2}] & /@ {Sin, Cos};
ListPlot[{data1, data2},
  PlotStyle ->
    {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], Red], Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], Blue]},
  BaseStyle -> 18,
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Wavelength (nm)", "k,n values"},
  PlotLegends -> {"k values", "n values"},
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: plot]