# Adding legend to Show

Tags: plotting, legending, slideshows

I want to add legend to `Show`. I tried as below by the help of [how to add plotlegends in a show function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51880/how-to-add-plotlegends-in-a-show-function):

```
Show[des = PolarPlot[2 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}], 
      Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Column[{PointLegend[{Lighter[Yellow]}, {"Data"}], 
         LineLegend[{Darker[Blue]}, 
         {"f(x)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\[ExponentialE]\), \\(-x\)]\)"}]}],
         RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{0.8, 0.85}]]]
```

But the legend comes in the graph. I failed to put it out of the graph. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases, you can treat them as separate objects and combine with `Grid`

```
Grid[{{PolarPlot[2 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}], 
       Framed[Column[{PointLegend[{Lighter[Yellow]}, {"Data"}], 
        LineLegend[{Darker[Blue]}, {"f(x)=x e^x"}]}], RoundingRadius -> 5]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eplog does not allow you to rescale the image, so here I do it before with PlotRangePadding

```
    Show[des = 
  PolarPlot[2 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 4}, 0}], 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[
    Column[{PointLegend[{Lighter[Yellow]}, {"Data"}], 
      LineLegend[{Darker[
         Blue]}, {"f)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\[ExponentialE]\), \
\\(-x\)]\)"}]}], RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{0.72, 0.8}]]]
```

out =[image]

Comment: I think you do not want it to say "f(x)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\[ExponentialE]\), \\(-x\)]\)" right? did you copy it right? there is also an extra opening curly bracket in your code (or one closing to few)

Answer (score -1):

```
PolarPlot[2 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed},
 PlotLegends ->
  LineLegend[{Dashed, Gray},
   {TraditionalForm[f[x] == x e^x]},
   LegendFunction -> "Panel",
   LegendLabel -> "Data"]]
```

[image]