# Frame and Fontsize of legends

Tags: plotting, legending

If I have the following code:

```
data={{-1., 53.260026873285206}, {-0.5228787452803376, 
   54.87380209619239}, {0., 56.1639882116586}, {Log[3]/Log[10], 
   58.84342746705887}, {1, 61.23327329308531}, {Log[30]/Log[10], 
   63.24477900953466}, {2, 66.81745692936386}, {Log[300]/Log[10], 
   69.93149162170488}, {Log[600]/Log[10], 71.4829226089971}, {3, 
   72.18449065001315}, {-2.3010299956639813, 
   54.00231502199229}, {-(Log[60]/Log[10]), 
   55.1941444178587}, {-(Log[20]/Log[10]), 56.003834022541035}, {-1,56.949679030549746}, {-(Log[6]/Log[10]), 
   57.3050045190135}, {-(Log[10/3]/Log[10]), 
   57.72132372329668}, {-(Log[2]/Log[10]), 
   58.24888194249831}, {-2.3010299956639813, 
   54.03670125564749}, {-(Log[60]/Log[10]), 
   55.11571197888246}, {-(Log[20]/Log[10]), 56.17041542461532}, {-1,
    56.71167863055032}, {-(Log[6]/Log[10]), 
   57.25059302294601}, {-(Log[10/3]/Log[10]), 
   57.70966183063876}, {-(Log[2]/Log[10]), 58.106793148660984}};

   ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"All Data"}, {0.2, 0.8}], Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> 16, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
     Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})]
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

I have two questions:

1) How can I put a frame to the legend (e.g "All Data") keeping the same position?
2) How can I make the legend bigger?

EDIT:

If I have a second data and Legend and I include it to plot it with `Show` such as:

```
data2 = {{2, 66.9795853828354}, {Log[300]/Log[10], 70.1}, {Log[600]/
    Log[10], 71.7}, {3, 72.3}, {-2.3010299956639813, 
    54.}, {-(Log[60]/Log[10]), 55.1}, {-(Log[20]/Log[10]), 56.}, {-1, 
    56.9}, {-(Log[6]/Log[10]), 57.3}, {-(Log[10/3]/Log[10]), 
    57.7}, {-(Log[2]/Log[10]), 58.2}, {-2.3, 
    54.}, {-(Log[60]/Log[10]), 55.1}, {-(Log[20]/Log[10]), 56.1}, {-1,
     56.7}, {-(Log[6]/Log[10]), 57.2}, {-(Log[10/3]/Log[10]), 
    57.7}, {-(Log[2]/Log[10]), 58.1}};

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"All Data"}, {0.2, 0.8}], Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> 16, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
      Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})], 
 ListPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"All Data"}, {0.2, 0.7}]]]
```

Which gives:

[image]

3) How can I do the same but both Legends in the same frame, together with their data points?

Comment: I get lots of  errors when I run your code,

Comment: John, you've posted quite a few questions, so you should know by now that we need COMPLETE code, including the data needed to run it. It is also best to produce a **minimal working example** that reproduces the problem. In your case, none of the formatting is relevant to the problem, so you could take it out. That helps because it brings your problem to the fore and allows people to focus on it. But remember, first and foremost, if I can't run your code, I can't fix your code! If your code is too big, just make up some numbers just for the question.

Comment: @MarcoB I have EDITED the question to make it workable and so that it works as a minimal working example. Thanks

Comment: @Nasser I edited the question to make it work and to make it easier. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Please take into account that in my actual code I have two legends and I am plotting two figures together with `Show` so that it is workable also with `Show` and more Legends. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I put a frame to the legend (e.g "All Data") keeping the same
>   position?

```
ListPlot[data,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"All Data"}, 
            LegendFunction -> (Framed[Style[#]] &)], {0.2, 0.8}],
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 FrameStyle -> 16,
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
     Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})
 ]
```

[image]

2) How can I make the legend bigger?

```
ListPlot[data,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"All Data"}, 
        LegendFunction -> (Framed[Style[#, 20]] &)], {0.2, 0.8}],
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 FrameStyle -> 16,
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
     Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})
 ]
```

[image]

---

**Update for two data**

```
ListPlot[{data, data2},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"data1", "data2"}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#] &)], {0.2, 0.8}],
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 FrameStyle -> 16,
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
     Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})
 ]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{data, data2},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"data1", "data2"}, 
       LegendFunction -> (Framed[Style[#, 18]] &)], {0.2, 0.8}],
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 FrameStyle -> 16,
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
     Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Nasser thank you very much!. One question: Is it possible to put the Legend point (e,g the red point) inside the frame as well?. 

Also, if I have another legend for another plot using `Show` how can I also put that Legend in the same Frame?. If I use the code it will do it manually for each but both will not be included in the same frame. Is this possible as well?. I appreciate your help again in advanced

Comment: @John please provide a second MWE of what you want, which includes 2 legends to add in this case. I used the MWE you provided which has only one legend.  I'll see if it possible to include the point as well inside.

Comment: Nasser, I have made an EDIT to include the second set of data and make more especific the question, Thanks !

Comment: @John updated for 2 data. You can play with `Frame` setting there to change it more, spacing, etc... see help on `Frame` as needed. I think it is better to use one plot command and not use Show to combine them.

Comment: Thank you Nasser!!!! This works great!. Just one more thing if you don't mind and if it is not to difficult. Is it possible too do it with the command `Show` as I had it? I have all my long code with plots using `Show`.?

Comment: @John you can do it with `Show` but need to do lots of Manual construction and it gets messy. See [how-to-add-plotlegends-in-a-show-function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51880/how-to-add-plotlegends-in-a-show-function)  I would recommend changing your Show to one Plot. It should not be hard to do this change, just replace `Show[ plot[data1..],plot[data2,...]]` with `plot[{data1,data2},...]`  and now you can make the Legends much easier. But again, if you want to use Show, then the above linked answer shows how.

Comment: Nasser, thanks! I saw this post before. The problem with my particular code is that inside the `Show` I have not only `ListPlot` but also `Plot` and in this way if I use your code it wouldn't work because I cannot use `ListPlot[{data, data2}...etc` as I also have `Plot` inside my `Show`. That is the main reason that for my particular case it would be better to do this with `Show` if possible. Inside the `Show` I have a `Plot` function that contains a fitted model and that's the reason I need to use `Plot`.

Comment: `I have not only ListPlot but also Plot` it then would have been better to show your MWE doing the above, your MWE only shows both using `ListPlot`.  But if you have seen the above linked to answer before, why not use that answer for your needs? It already shows how do it with Show? Did it not work for you for some reason?  my answer to add legends to Show is not going to be really much different that what the above link shows.

Comment: Nasser, I was already able to do it taking a better look at the link you provided. I appreciate your help a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you want a frame around the whole legend

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{Style["All Data", 14]}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
        FrameMargins -> Tiny] &)], {0.2, 0.8}], Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> 16, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
     Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})]
```

[image]

Comment: Rohit! Thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted. Could you also take a look at the last edit I made to include two different legends in the same frame and make them bigger?